# Remove all instances of (substring plus next character) in string in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

Using Swift's .range() and/or .index(), I am wanting to find and remove every instance of not only "!" but also the character immediately after it. I can remove "!" easily, but it's the "next character" which I can't do in an elegant manner.

So in the below, I'm trying to remove "!x" and "!z" from str such that string ultimately becomes "abcdef"

```
var str = "abc!xde!zf"    

while let pos = str.index(of: "!") {
    str.remove(at: pos) // this removes "!"
    // ??? (remove character AFTER "!" as well)
    print(str)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of removing a substring in a couple ways:

```
while let range = str.range(of: "!") {
    str.removeSubrange(range.lowerBound...range.upperBound)
}
```

or

```
while let index = str.index(of: "!") {
    let end = str.index(after: index)
    str.removeSubrange(index...end)
}
```

By using `...` you will remove one character beyond the range of the character you are looking for.

You'll probably want to add a check that ! is not the last character of a string.

Comment: Nice, yeah I can add last char checks. I know there is limitedBy option for index but unsure if that factors into this at all

Comment: @iamnotsam You can use limitedBy the string endIndex combined with nil coalescing operator and use the endIndex as the default value but you would need to use the closed range operator `..<` and offset two positions

Comment: `str.removeSubrange(index..<(str.index(index, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: str.endIndex) ?? str.endIndex))`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `str.remove(at: pos)` twice. The first `remove` removes the `!`, after that all characters indices after the `!` are shifted by one and thus calling `str.remove(at: pos)` a second time, the character after the `!` is removed.

Your code would be:

```
str.remove(at: pos)
str.remove(at: pos)
```

Comment: Edge case: consecutive '!'.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you are right, but that specific case did not get mentioned by OP.

Comment: Yup, just something to be aware of.

Comment: ha this is exactly what I did at first but it started gnawing at me, knowing there was some range-y solution. Thank you

Comment: This isn't safe. If the character after the `"!"` has a different encoded size (e.g. if it's a complex emoji like `""`), this will corrupt the string. Mutating a string invalidates existing indices. More generally, mutating any collection potentially invalidates any existing index into that collection.

Comment: I might add, even if this solution worked, it would be less efficient than calling `removeSubrange` with a two-character range. When a character is deleted, the string has to move all succeeding characters down in memory, and it's better to do this once than twice.

Answer (score 2):

For that kind of dynamic replacement *Regular Expression* might be a good alternative:

```
let str = "abc!xde!zf"
let trimmedString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\!+.?", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The pattern considers one or more exclamation marks followed by an optional character so it works also with a trailing `!`

However it does not work with complex characters like emojis.

Comment: brilliant, being new to Swift it is good to know that you can do regex in a shorter way than examples I've seen with NSRegularExpression which seem verbose in comparison